# This guy keeps asking the same type of question

Tags: discussion, users

Just look at his [recent questions](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/4497/user72728). And I'm pretty sure we've told him in comments, but he keeps asking them. Perhaps the moderators can warn him?

Comment: I agree it seems problematic. Is it technically against the rules since in some way they are different questions? What should be said/done?

Comment: @jmbejara I would say these are all duplicates. He should have phrased one general question that applies to all his questions (be it category X or country Y), instead of asking for micro-questions for every single one. Note that he actually got some useful advice on one of his earlier questions. If he asks new questions on similar matter after that, he should emphasize how they are different (and interesting to other users).